# ASP.NET MVC: return view (ActionName, Model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a model to an action by using the `return view (ActionName, Model)`. I already know about `TempData` but my question is that when I have a few textboxes in the razor for that model, like for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor (x=> x.Field1)
And
@Html.TextBoxFor (x=> x.Field2)
```

When I use `TempData` together with `RedirectToAction`, the data in the model is loaded into my fields very well but when I use the `return View ("ActionName", MyModel)`, it throws the `Value cannot be null exception`.

How I'm doing it is so:

```
public ActionResult Act1 () {
     Model M = new Model () {Field1="123", Field2="245"};
     return View("Act2", M);
}
```

This throws the exception while this method works:

```
   public ActionResult Act1 () {
     Model M = new Model () {Field1="123", Field2="245"};
     TempData["Model"] = M;
     return RedirectToAction ("Act2");
     // then casting the TempData in the Act2 back to M and it works!
}
```

My question is that, why the Act1 method causes the error ? (The razor part is exactly the same, asking this question out of curiosity)

Edit:

```
 // Without TempData

 public ActionResult Act2 (Model model) {
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your second Action code `Act2`?

Comment: Are you expecting `return View("Act2", M);` to call the `Act2` action? If that's what you want to do, then do this: `return Act2(M);`

Comment: @JasonP: That would cause another error :D, related to route path

Comment: @PierreOverFlow Are those two actions in the same controller?

Comment: @JasonP: Yeah exactly, they are in the same controller and the Act1 is supposed to fill some fields when needed, that's why I'm filling the model in the Act1 Action. Just edited this comment

Comment: `return View("Act2")` does not execute the `Act2` action, it renders `Act2.cshtml` and returns it. I think that's the answer to your question. As for a different solution, I think that depends your project's requirements.

Comment: @JasonP: So even if it doesn't, shouldn't it pass the model to the view ?

Comment: It should, yes. Can you post the actual code where the exception is occurring? With the code you've shown us, there's no way `M` could be null.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you've shown can't possibly exhibit the results  you're suggesting.  If you don't believe me, create a very simple blank project that does just that, and you'll see that it works.  Obviously, your real code is doing something different.  Is your class *actually* called Model?  That could be interfering with the Razor reserved word Model.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code as is now you need to add return `View()`

```
public ActionResult Act1 () {
     Model M = new Model () {Field1="123", Field2="245"};
     return View("Act2", M);
}
```

Comment: @PierreOverFlow can you please show some of the code in the view? like what does it accept for model? do you iterate through it in anyway?

Comment: No, it is just a very simple Model, two string fields, I'm only curious why it doesn't work while tempdata works well, the model has two properties of string type, so two TextBoxes in the Razor to load the model and that's all.

Comment: I'm asking this because I've read that these two ways of passing model to an action are somehow equal.

Answer (score 0):

In your view `Act2` surround your `TempData[Model]` with an `if` clause and then check if it is not null use it else don't use it. I presume it is the problem. That is why when you try to use it it throws an exception as you attempt it but it is null.

```
 if (TempData[Model]!=null)
    {

   //Attempt it here and cast it here
    }
 else
  {
   //Use your model 
  }
```

Comment: The tempData already works, I wanna now why the model that is passed to action using return View ("Act2", M) is null.

Comment: Could you show then the View. I don't think the `model` is null

Comment: No it said the model that was passed contained two Null fields

Comment: I know how to solve this problem using TempData, but I wanna know why the return View ("ActionName", Model) that is claimed to be the same, doesn't work, that is the problem.

Comment: `return View()` and `return RedirectToAction()` are NOT the same. One renders a view and returns it, and the other tells the browser to redirect to a different url.

Comment: Just try my answer before casting

Comment: well you have to change the TempData to if (Model == null) in your answer, because, nothing is wrong with the TempData, it is absolutely ok. I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @pierreOverflow as you use the same view `Act2` and try to cast the TempData. You have a success on the `Act1` because the TempData is not null anymore. But in the second when you will use your `TempData` it will be `null`. Nothing seems wrong with the model.